# Rust Serde Serializing Iso8601 Time adds +00 prefix with quick_xml

Tags: rust, serde

I cannot for the life of me figure out why a "+00" prefix is being added to the serialized OffsetDateTime in my struct.

Here is an MRP: [link](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Aquick-xml%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%220.29.0%22%2C%20features%3D%5B%20%22serialize%22%20%5D%20%7D%0Aserde%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%221.0.147%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%20%22derive%22%20%5D%20%7D%0Atime%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%220.3.17%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%20%22serde%22%2C%20%22parsing%22%2C%20%22formatting%22%20%5D%20%7D%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20serde%3A%3A%7BSerialize%7D%3B%0Ause%20time%3A%3AOffsetDateTime%3B%0Ause%20quick_xml%3A%3Ase%3A%3ASerializer%3B%0A%20%20%20%20use%20time%3A%3Aformat_description%3A%3Awell_known%3A%3Aiso8601%3A%3AIso8601%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Serialize)%5D%0A%23%5Bserde(rename_all%20%3D%20%22camelCase%22)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20Wrapper%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%23%5Bserde(with%20%3D%20%22time%3A%3Aserde%3A%3Aiso8601%22)%5D%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20time%3A%20OffsetDateTime%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20buf%20%3D%20String%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ser%20%3D%20Serializer%3A%3Awith_root(%26mut%20buf%2C%20Some(%22FooBar%22)).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ts%20%3D%20Wrapper%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20time%3A%20OffsetDateTime%3A%3Aparse(%222010-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%20%26Iso8601%3A%3ADEFAULT).unwrap()%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20ts.serialize(ser).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20buf)%3B%0A%7D)

I annotate my struct in the following way:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Wrapper {
    #[serde(with = "time::serde::iso8601")]
    pub time: OffsetDateTime,
}
```

But the result is the following string:

```
+002010-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z
```

Perhaps this is a quick_xml bug? I have begun digging into quick_xml, but I was hoping someone might have encountered this issue.

Comment: Is this actually a problem for you? As Chayim points out, a standard compliant parser should be able to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time` crate serializes the year as six digits. I guess to be more future-proof in case your code survives 8,000 years? Not sure. [The standard permits that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years). But you aren't supposed to be reading the serialization format anyway, so as long as both the serializer and deserializer agree on the number of digits, everything is fine.

The standard also requires a plus or minus sign in case of expanded year digits.

**Edit:** Found a github issue that talks about that: [#548](https://github.com/time-rs/time/issues/548), and it also tells how to serialize using four digits:

```rust
use time::format_description::well_known::{Iso8601, iso8601};
const FORMAT: _ = Iso8601<{ iso8601::Config::DEFAULT.set_year_is_six_digits(false).encode() }>;
time::serde::format_description!(my_format, OffsetDateTime, FORMAT);
```

> That generates a `my_format` module that you can use in conjunction with `#[serde(with)]`.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that reference. As my code will certainly survive for _at least_ another 7,999 years, this gives me quite a lot of relief. Unfortunately, since I am serializing this code for consumption by another service (not controlled by me), I'm not so sure that their deserialization will be as conformant to the spec. I guess we'll see what happens (and hope that I don't need to write custom serialization logic to deal with other broken specs). Thanks!

Comment: @clo_jur You can always serialize this by yourself and use the formatting options of `time` to format with four digits.

Comment: @clo_jur Ah! Found a github issue that specifies a solution. Edited.